# How to get URL image from Firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase

I am new to programming and I am trying to create an Angular app. I need to upload photos into firebase and also get the URl in order to show the picture. here is my code:

```
chooseFiles(event) {
this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
if (this.selectedFiles.item(0))
  this.uploadpic();  
}

uploadpic() {
let file = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
let uniqkey = 'pic' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
const uploadTask = this.storage.upload('/angfire2store/' + uniqkey,  file);
this.imgsrc = uploadTask.downloadURL();
};
```

It seems that downloadURL() it is not working anymore with firestorage. Can you please help me with one solution? I also tried getDownloadUrl() but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

`downloadURL` method returns `Observable` so if you eg. showing `imgsrc` variable in template the `async` pipe should be enough.

The other case could be that you want assign to `imgsrc` just url so this is a way:

```
uploadTask.downloadURL().subscribe(url => this.imgsrc = url);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to display it in the component. Just bind the result of the url that you got from firebase to a class variable and then show it in the template. You can do it like this:

```
imageURL: string = '';

uploadpic() {
let file = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
let uniqkey = 'pic' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
const pathFile='/angfire2store/' + uniqkey;
const uploadTask = this.storage.upload(pathFile, file).then(() => {
     const ref = this.storage.ref(pathFile);
     const downloadURL = ref.getDownloadURL().subscribe(url => { 
     const this.imageURL = url;
     console.log(Url);
 });
})
```

Then in your template file you can bind the src of the image like this:

```
<img [src]="imagePath" />
```

You are trying to display the const Url which is in the scope of the uloadpic function and is not accessible outside of it.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! i have fixed it like this:

```
uploadpic() {
let file = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
let uniqkey = 'pic' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
const pathFile='/angfire2store/' + uniqkey;
const uploadTask = this.storage.upload(pathFile, file).then(() => {
     const ref = this.storage.ref(pathFile);
     const downloadURL = ref.getDownloadURL().subscribe(url => { 
     const Url = url;
     console.log(Url);
 });

})
```

but I still can not show it on the page. I have tried with img src='{{url}}' and also {{url |async }} but still no result.